# Iterate over array list jquery and then make some changes in object properties .Create a new array list after changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array list and i am iterating over it using jquery map .while iterating i want to make changes to object properties and create a new array list . Any suggestion,idea ,help will be appreciated .

This is 'm.data' in console ->  Array(10)

Now what I want to achieve is iterating over data and changing object[0].Name to something else and then again create final 'new Array' after changes in object properties

```js
let m = {
  data: [
   {Id: 600, Name: "rety", Description: "ssa", Number: 135, type: "meter"},
   {Id:624, Name: "xyz", Description: null, Number: 134, type: "PC"},
   {Id: 645, Name: "abcd", Description: null, DNumber: 142, type: "pcs"},
   {Id: 664, Name: "dfdf", Description: null, Number: 134, type: "PC"}
  ]
};

var _newarray = $.map(m.data, function(i, obj) {
  for (var prop in obj) {
    //I WANT TO MAKE CHANGES TO OBJ.NAME SAY AND AGAIN MAKE A NEW ARRAY
  }
});
```

Comment: Which exactly changes you need to make?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] by adding the input and the expected output

Comment: ok wait doing...

Comment: Please check this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/. As it says in `callback` function it will have first parameter as `object` and second as `index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/. As it says in `callback` function it will have first parameter as `object` and second as `index`.

```js
let m = {
  data: [
   {Id: 600, Name: "rety", Description: "ssa", Number: 135, type: "meter"},
   {Id:624, Name: "xyz", Description: null, Number: 134, type: "PC"},
   {Id: 645, Name: "abcd", Description: null, DNumber: 142, type: "pcs"},
   {Id: 664, Name: "dfdf", Description: null, Number: 134, type: "PC"}
  ]
};

// set property name into object to updte dynamical property
let propName = 'Name';

var _newarray = $.map(m.data, function(obj) {
  // copy object with Object.assign
  let newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
  // update required property. Use propName to set property
  newObj[propName] = 'new value - ' + obj[propName];
  // return object
  return newObj;
});

console.log(_newarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi @Karan is there another way we can write this line  newObj.name = 'new name'; because we have dynamic object properties.

Comment: You can set your property name to object `let propName = 'Name';` and use it like `newObj[propName] = 'value'`, it will update `newObj.Name` value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `map`, just use `for-of`.

```js
list1 = [{name: "item1"}, {name: "item2"}]
list2 = []

for(const item of list1) {
  new_item = Object.assign({}, item); 
  new_item.name = item.name+"-modified"
  list2.push(new_item)
}

console.log(list1)
console.log(list2)
```

Comment: You can simply use `Object.assign({}, obj);` instead of creating your own `function`.